# Passing variable to Magento widget

Tags: magento, variables, widget, block

I'm trying to pass a variable using setData to a box containing a widget with this:

```
$this->getChild('my_box')->setData('myvar', '123');
echo $this->getChildHtml('my_box');
```

or this:

```
echo $this->getChild('my_box')->setData('myvar', '123')->toHtml();
```

The "my_box" is the block linked with the widget, it's positioned in the footer and defined in local.xml:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="my_box" as="my_box" translate="label">
        <label>My Box</label>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But if I try to retrieve the value in the widget with any of these methods:

```
echo $this->getData('myvar');
echo $this->getMyVar();
echo $this->myvar;
```

there is no return value, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of a rewrite, `"core/text_list"` is an instance of [`Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php#L33) and would not have a template for you to call your code.

You can verify that the basic functionality is working, though:

```
$my_box = $this->getChild('my_box')->setData('myvar','123'); //if no error, my_box exists!

echo get_class($my_box); //Mage_Core_Block_Text_List

var_dump($my_box->debug()); //array() including 'myvar' => '123'

echo $my_box->getData('myvar')` //correct
echo $my_box->myvar //works, but unconventional
echo $my_box->getMyVar() //will not access the property you set; rather...
echo $my_box->getMyvar() //will work
```

For other fun, you can set properties via layout XML:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="my_box" as="my_box" translate="label">
        <label>My Box</label>
        <action method="setMyvar">
            <arbitrary>123</arbitrary>
        </action>
        <!-- or <action method="setDatar">
            <name>myvar</name>
            <val>123</arbitrary>
        </action> -->
    </block>
</reference>
```

Also, do be aware the the footer block is permanently cached in the **block_html** cache by default.